# Can you setup recive call in System.Net.Sockets to behave as winsocket2 WSARecv with MSG_PUSH_IMMEDIATE flag set

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, winsock2

I am connecting to server that doesn't set PSH flag on its TCP packets. As latency is important I need to ignore PSH flag on receive and forward whatever is in the buffer immediately.

This is possible in winsock2 api with WSARecv function and MSG_PUSH_IMMEDIATE flag. Is same functionality possible with .net socket?

Comment: I can't see a way to do it.  Can you try: ``var socketFlags = (SocketFlags)0x20; s.Receive(buffer, socketFlags);`` looking at the source code, these flags are passed all the way through to ``WSARecv()`` - a long shot but it might work.

Comment: The PSH flag is 50 years old and was used with 50 BAUD Telnet Terminals and have no use these days with Ethernet Rates of > 10M

Comment: First the bit was left in to be backwards compatible.  Setting the flag to zero is not used.The purpose of the bit was to send data an not wait until ~1500 bits before bits were ready to send.  At slow speed it was more efficient to wait until more data was available (PSH = 0). The overhead of sending packets would slow down the transfer rate.  When PSH = 0 there were less packets but more latency.When TCP  got faster the latency was important so PSH=1 was always used.  Imagine you were sending a packet a second with 100 bytes.With PSH=0 you would wait 15 seconds before sending the packets.

Comment: @jdweng I suggest you check with a tcpdump, you will see a single stream between two machines with the PSH flag set and sometimes not set.  If the PSH flag is not set the OS can sometimes hang onto  the payload before making it available to the applications buffer.  On windows with ``TCP_DELAYED_ACK`` this can be up to 200ms.  If the PSH flag is set the OS should ACK it immediately and make it available to the application buffer immediately without the 200ms delay.  You might be thinking about something else?  But the PSH bit is most certainly used today by all current TCP stacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [Rowan Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1655868/rowan-smith) idea works. I added `(SocketFlags)0x20` to BeginReceive()  function and it got propagated to the WSARecv() function in the background so latency was removed.

I checked .net framework 4.5.1 and 4.8 and both implementations just pass SocketFlags to WSARecv() without using or modifying them.

Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Just be aware that this could break in future releases.

Comment: I know. I will check when we move versions.